# how to use different distance formula other than euclidean distance in k means

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I am working with latitude longitude data. I have to make clusters based on distance between two points. Now distance between two different point is `=ACOS(SIN(lat1)*SIN(lat2)+COS(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon2-lon1))*6371`

I want to use k means in R. Is there any way I can override distance calculation in that process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367133/using-k-nn-in-r-with-categorical-values

Comment: @Dan kruchinin no in order to use knn you must have ground truth data (supervised learning) but I don't have one

Comment: sorry, my bad. Not enough coffee :)

Comment: Have a look at `cluster:::pam()` [klick](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Partitioning_Around_Medoids_%28PAM%29), where you can supply a distance matrix.

Comment: @EDI Thanks :) it looks good. Let me try this

Comment: @EDi This is not working also. First problem is in order to have a dissimilarity matrix metric options are "euclidean" and "manhattan" only can not put my formula there. second problem I tried to calculate  Dissimilarity Matrix using daisy() but got an error "Error in double((n * (n - 1))/2) : vector size specified is too large". I have nearly 200000 observations

Comment: Maybe consider "preclustering" using some approximate distance function, and running subsets of your data?

Comment: `pam()` can take as input a dissimilarity matrix (see docs...). For computation of this matrix, maybe a solution would be to calculate it in C++ via RCPP.

Comment: The code in [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20584587/) uses `pam(...)` with a distance matrix created using a custom distance function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## K-means is not distance based

It is based on **variance minimization**. The sum-of-variance formula equals the *sum of squared Euclidean distances*, but the converse, **for other distances, will *not* hold**.

If you want to have an k-means like algorithm for other distances (where the mean is not an appropriate estimator), use **k-medoids** (PAM). In contrast to k-means, k-medoids will converge with arbitrary distance functions!

For Manhattan distance, you can also use K-medians. The median is an appropriate estimator for L1 norms (the median minimizes the sum-of-differences; the mean minimizes the sum-of-squared-distances).

For your particular use case, you could also transform your data into 3D space, then use (squared) Euclidean distance and thus k-means. But your cluster centers will be somewhere underground!

Comment: First I tried K means and then I used PAM. Yes in PAM I can pass a distance matrix but it has to know the number of clusters at the start. I don't think one can have that kind of information when you are working with the GPS data set of 200000 observation

Comment: For k-means you also need to know the number of clusters first. So PAM doesn't have a disadvantage there either. If you don't know the number of observations, you can try to run it with different k and evalutate which result fits your data best. Or use an algorithm such as DBSCAN, which doesn't need to know the number of clusters beforehand. k-means and it's variants - which optimize some *mathematical* quantity - all heavily rely on `k`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Following Function to calculate the earths distance, doesn't need an existing R function. I found this function on Stackoverflow, just can't remember the link to the article. However, I've validated it with GPS cumulative distance calculations and it aligns.

```
earthDist <- function (lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2){
  rad <- pi/180
  a1 <- lat1 * rad
  a2 <- lon1 * rad
  b1 <- lat2 * rad
  b2 <- lon2 * rad
  dlon <- b2 - a2
  dlat <- b1 - a1
  a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
  c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
  R <- 6378.145
  d <- R * c
  return(d)
}
```

call the function, using the following function :

```
CalculateCumaltiveDist <- function(x,y,id) {

    # #Initiate a vectro P
    km <- vector()
    # #Starting Value is 0, because its home
    km[1] <- 0

    #Loop through the earthly distance function between the first and Nth Row
    for(i in 2:NROW(df)){


      t <-  earthDist(  x[i-1], y[i-1] ,x[i], y[i])
      km[i] <- t

      if( i == 2 ) {

       tmp_All <- data.frame(id[i],x[i], y[i],km[i])

              } else if(i > 2) {

        tmp_All <- rbind(tmp_All, data.frame(id[i],x[i], y[i],km[i]))

        }

    }


    return(sum(tmp_All$km.i., na.rm = T))
}
```

if you want the data frame, remove final return sum function.

This will allow you to calculate distance between every single obs-1 and obs in the data frame.

if you want a pairwise distance calculation, then use the earth distance function and loop through between obs[1]:[200000] and obs[1:200000] until all pairwise combinations are calculated. Then transpose this data in to a matrix and you should have a distance matrix.

hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data.frame, `df`, with columns for `lat` and `long`, then you should be able to use the `earth.dist(...)` function in the `fossil` package to calculate a distance matrix, and pass that to `pam(...)` in the `cluster` package to do the clustering.

```
library(fossil)
library(cluster)
df    <- data.frame(long=<longituces>, lat=<latitudes>))
dist  <- earth.dist(df, dist=T)
clust <- pam(dist, k, diss=T)
```

See [earth.dist(...)](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fossil/docs/earth.dist), and [pam(...)](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/cluster/pam) for documentation

Comment: again dist  <- earth.dist(df, dist=T) not working because of large dataset.

Comment: Thanks by the way this is working for small data sets.